# Unexpected response code 503 Error when Call JSON on hostinger.com

Tags: java, php, android, html, android-studio

I use JSONObject to get JSON PHP from Server,

The Code is working **fine** on **000webhost.com** server, but when I Upgrade to **hostinger** it's not working.
everything is correct on my COD and PHP and connected fine with the database, 
**is this because of SSL and VPN. ??**
**is JSONObject not working  unless theirs SSL Certificate?**
**is because is link must start with s HTTPS not HTTP?**

1. `String urlConnection ="https://solvable-extension.000webhostapp.com/selectNoty.php"; // Working Fine`
2. `String urlConnection = "http://osama.hostingerapp.com/php/selectNoty.php"; // Not Work`

please find the two link and the code

```
 requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

//String urlConnection ="https://solvable-extension.000webhostapp.com/selectNoty.php"; //Working Fine
        String urlConnection = "http://osama.hostingerapp.com/php/selectNoty.php"; //Not Work

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlConnection, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {

                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("All_users");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject emp = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                               String name = emp.getString("name");
                                t1.setText(name);
                                Log.d("noty_dp", "noty_dp: " + name);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", "Error");
            }

        });
        requestQueue.add(request);
```

#### the Error Locate is :

```
E/Volley: [7552] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 503 for http://osama.hostingerapp.com/php/selectNoty.php
```

Comment: Seems there are a lot of Google results around just this, even hostinger specific. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i was searching for 1 month trying to fiend the answer , but i didn't found anything 

Comment: https://support.hostinger.com/en/articles/3417446-what-is-503-error-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: @zgc7009 it's a "fake" help article from Hostinger: I think they are blocking access to php from anything but a browser on purpose. You can do a hundred of requests in an hour for same php file using a browser, and it works fine, but if you do just ONE request in a DAY from an app or a script, you get a "503 error". Ironically, when you ask for support... they say "go asking on stackoverflow.com"...